# Simplest Ruby code for SQS request signing?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, digital-signature, amazon-sqs, tropo

I am working in the cool but very constrained environment of [Tropo](http://tropo.com) (cloud telephony) Ruby scripting. The entire app is a single JRuby file. No gems, no requires.

I need to send simple messages to a single SQS queue. I don't need to do any other SQS operations. Before I start pulling code out of existing gems to do this, I wanted to see if anyone has standalone code for sending SQS messages or code that does the HTTP request signing that SQS requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up going with the following super-simple code to post a message to an SQS queue that already exists. No gems required.

[super_simple_sqs.rb](https://gist.github.com/901024)